# Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC Popup Grid Cant Post Create Request And Fail With 404 Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo  popup grid and when I try to Create Request ,it is firing 404 error.

Here is My request:`/Admin/SptsData/CreatePersons`

Admin is area.SptsData is controller and CreatePersons is method.

**Here is my grid setup:**

```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="widget wgreen">
    <div class="widget-head">
        <div class="pull-left">Veri İşlemleri</div>
        <div class="widget-icons pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="wminimize"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="padd">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Domain.DataModel.ViewModels.SptsDataViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.TcKimlik);
        //columns.Bound(p => p.Uyruk);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Ad);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Soyad);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Cinsiyet);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DogumTarihi);
        columns.Bound(p => p.KurumKodu);
        //columns.Bound(p => p.KurumAdi);

        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit().UpdateText("Güncelle/Oluştur").Text("Düzenle").CancelText("İptal");
            command.Custom("Sil").Click("deleteConfirm");

        }).Width(200);
    })
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Yeni Kayıt"))
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel().Text("Excel'e Aktar"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("CreatePersonTemplate").Window(w => w.Width(500)))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Messages(msg =>
        {
            msg.Empty("Gösterilecek herhangi bir veri yok.");
            msg.Display("Toplam {0} kayıttan {1} ile {2} arası gösteriliyor.");
            msg.First("İlk Sayfa");
            msg.Last("Son Sayfa");
            msg.Next("Sonraki");
            msg.Previous("Önceki");
            msg.Refresh("Yenile");
            msg.MorePages("Diğer Sayfalar");
            msg.Of("{0} ın");
        })
        )

    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Messages(msg =>
    {
        msg.And("Ve");
        msg.Cancel("İptal");
        msg.CheckAll("Tümünü İşaretle");
        msg.Clear("Temizle");
        msg.Equals("Eşittir");
        msg.Filter("Filtrele");
        msg.Info("Alan Bilgisi");
        msg.IsFalse("Olmayan");
        msg.IsTrue("Olan");
        msg.Or("Ya Da");
        msg.Search("Ara");
        msg.SelectValue("Değer Seç");
        msg.Value("Değer");
    })
    .Operators(ops =>
    {
        ops.ForString(str =>
        {
            str.Contains("İçerir");
            str.DoesNotContain("İçermez");
            str.EndsWith("İle Biten");
            str.IsEmpty("Boş Olan");
            str.IsEqualTo("Eşiti Olan");
            str.IsNotEmpty("Boş Olmayan");
            str.IsNotEqualTo("Eşiti Olmayan");
            str.IsNull("Değer İçermeyen");
            str.IsNotNull("Değer İçeren");
            str.StartsWith("İle Başlayan");
        });

        ops.ForDate(dt =>
        {
            dt.IsEqualTo("Eşiti Olan");
            dt.IsGreaterThan("Büyüktür");
            dt.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Büyüktür Ya Da Eşittir");
            dt.IsLessThan("Küçüktür");
            dt.IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Küçüktür Ya Da Eşittir");
            dt.IsNotEqualTo("Eşit Değildir");
            dt.IsNotNull("Değer İçerir");
            dt.IsNull("Değer İçermez");
        });

        ops.ForEnums(en =>
        {
            en.IsEqualTo("Eşiti Olan");
            en.IsNotEqualTo("Eşit Değildir");
            en.IsNotNull("Değer İçerir");
            en.IsNull("Değer İçermez");
        });

        ops.ForNumber(dt =>
        {
            dt.IsEqualTo("Eşiti Olan");
            dt.IsGreaterThan("Büyüktür");
            dt.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Büyüktür Ya Da Eşittir");
            dt.IsLessThan("Küçüktür");
            dt.IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Küçüktür Ya Da Eşittir");
            dt.IsNotEqualTo("Eşit Değildir");
            dt.IsNotNull("Değer İçerir");
            dt.IsNull("Değer İçermez");
        });

    })


    )

    .Excel(excel => excel
            .FileName("kisiler.xlsx")
            .Filterable(true)
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExcelExportPersons", "Admin"))
        )
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Error("error_handler");
            events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");
        })
        .Model(model =>
           {
            model.Id(p => p.TcKimlik);
            model.Field(p => p.TcKimlik);
        })

        .Create(create => create.Action("CreatePersons", "SptsData"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPersons", "SptsData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditPerson", "SptsData"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("DestroyPerson", "SptsData"))
    )
            )

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("ConfirmDelete")
    .Title("Kayıt Silme İşlemi")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(500)
)

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">

    <div id="details-container">
        <h2><strong>#= TcKimlik #</strong> nolu kişiyi silmek istediğinize emin misiniz? </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions pull-right">
        <button id="yesButton" class="btn btn-success">Evet</button>
        <button id="noButton" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Hayır</button>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="client-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="widget wlightblue">
        <!-- Widget title -->
        <div class="widget-head">
            <div class="pull-left">Branş,Akademik Ünvan ve İdari Ünvan Bilgileri</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget-content">
            <table class="table  table-bordered ">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Branş Bilgisi</strong></td>
                        <td>#=BranchName#</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>İdari Ünvan</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="badge-important">#=ManagerialTitleName#</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Akademik Ünivan</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="badge-important">#=AcademicTitleName#</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function deleteConfirm(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        var grd = kendo.widgetInstance($('#grid'), kendo.ui);

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        var wnd = $("#ConfirmDelete").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
        wnd.center().open();

        $("#yesButton").click(function () {

            grd.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            grd.dataSource.sync();
            wnd.close();
        });
        $("#noButton").click(function () {
            wnd.close();
        });
    }


    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }


    }

    function onRequestEnd(e) {

        console.log(e.type);

        if (e.type === "create") {

            var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
                title: 'İşlem Başarılı!',
                text: 'Kaydetme işlemi başarılı.',
                sticky: false,
                time: 2000,
                class_name: 'gritter-custom'
            });

            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

            // You can have it return a unique id, this can be used to manually remove it later using
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.gritter.remove(unique_id, {
                    fade: true,
                    speed: 'slow'
                });
            }, 2000);

        } else if (e.type === "update") {

            var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
                title: 'İşlem Başarılı!',
                text: 'Güncelleme işlemi başarılı.',
                sticky: false,
                time: 2000,
                class_name: 'gritter-custom'
            });

            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

            // You can have it return a unique id, this can be used to manually remove it later using
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.gritter.remove(unique_id, {
                    fade: true,
                    speed: 'slow'
                });
            }, 2000);

        } else if (e.type === "destroy") {

            var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
                title: 'İşlem Başarılı!',
                text: 'Silme işlemi başarılı.',
                sticky: false,
                time: 2000,
                class_name: 'gritter-custom'
            });

            // You can have it return a unique id, this can be used to manually remove it later using
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.gritter.remove(unique_id, {
                    fade: true,
                    speed: 'slow'
                });
            }, 2000);

        }

    }


</script>

<script>
    function filterHospitals() {
        return {
            city: $("#City").val(),
            type: $("#KurumTur").val()
        };
    }

    function cityChanged(e) {
        var ds = $("#KurumTur").data("kendoComboBox").input.val("");
        var kurum = $("#KurumKodu").data("kendoComboBox");
        kurum.enable(false);
    }

    function filterHospitalTypes() {
        return {
            typeFilter: $("#KurumTur").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }

    function filterBranches() {
        return {
            brType: $("#BranchTypeName").val(),
            branchFilter: $("#BranchName").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }

    function hospitalTypeChanged() {
        var kurum = $("#KurumKodu").data("kendoComboBox");
        kurum.enable(true);
    }

    function filterAcademicTitle() {
        return {
            branch: $("#BranchName").val(),
            academicFilter: $("#AcademicTitleName").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }

    function filterManagerialTitle() {
        return {
            branch: $("#BranchName").val(),
            managerialFilter: $("#ManagerialTitleName").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }

</script>
```

**And Here is CreatePersonTemplate:**

```
@model Domain.DataModel.ViewModels.SptsDataViewModel



<div class="span12 form-group" id="spts_user_frm">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.TcKimlik)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.TcKimlik, new { style = "width:300px", placeholder = "TC Kimlik Numarasını Giriniz", @class = "form-control", @Value = "T.C." })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Ad)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Ad, new { style = "width:300px", placeholder = "Personelin Adını Giriniz", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Soyad)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Soyad, new { style = "width:300px", placeholder = "Personelin Soyadını Giriniz", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Cinsiyet)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.Cinsiyet)
          .Name("Cinsiyet")
          .Filter("contains")
          .Placeholder("Cinsiyet Seçiniz...")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Erkek", Value = "E"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Kadın", Value = "K"
              }
          })
          .Suggest(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.DogumTarihi)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(p => p.DogumTarihi)
          .Name("DogumTarihi")
          .Value(DateTime.Today)
          .Footer("Bugün - #=kendo.toString(data, 'd') #")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.City)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("City")
          .DataTextField("CityName")
          .DataValueField("CityCode")
          .BindTo(Model.Cities)
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("İl Seçiniz...")
          .Events(e =>
           {
               e.Change("cityChanged");
           })
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.KurumTur)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.KurumTur)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("KurumTur")
          .DataTextField("Type")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetHospitalTypes", "Custom")
                           .Data("filterHospitalTypes");
                      })
                      .ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
           .Events(e =>
                   {
                       e.Change("hospitalTypeChanged");
                   })
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("Kurum Turu Seçiniz...")
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.KurumKodu)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.KurumKodu)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("KurumKodu")
          .DataTextField("HospitalName")
          .DataValueField("HospitalId")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("Kurum Seçiniz...")
          .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetCascadeHospitalsByTypeAndCity", "Custom")
                              .Data("filterHospitals");
                      })
                      .ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
          .Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .CascadeFrom("KurumTur")
        )
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.BranchTypeName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.BranchTypeName)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("BranchTypeName")
          .DataTextField("BranchType")
          .DataValueField("BranchTypeId")
          .BindTo(Model.AllBranchTypes)
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("Branş Tipi Seçiniz...")
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.BranchName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.BranchName)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("BranchName")
          .DataTextField("BranchName")
          .DataValueField("BranchId")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("Branş Tipi Seçiniz...")
          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetCascadeBranches", "Custom")
                                      .Data("filterBranches");
                              })
                              .ServerFiltering(true);
                          })
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
          .CascadeFrom("BranchTypeName")
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.AcademicTitleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.AcademicTitleName)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("AcademicTitleName")
          .DataTextField("Title")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("Akademik Ünvanı Seçiniz...")
          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetCascadeAcademicTitles", "Custom")
                                      .Data("filterAcademicTitle");
                              })
                              .ServerFiltering(true);
                          })
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
          .CascadeFrom("BranchName")
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ManagerialTitleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.ManagerialTitleName)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("ManagerialTitleName")
          .DataTextField("Title")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .Placeholder("İdari Ünvanı Seçiniz...")
          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetCascadeManagerialTitles", "Custom")
                                      .Data("filterManagerialTitle");
                              })
                              .ServerFiltering(true);
                          })
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
          .CascadeFrom("BranchName")
        )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.StaffStatuName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(p => p.StaffStatuName)
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .Name("StaffStatuName")
          .DataTextField("Statu")
          .DataValueField("StaffStatuId")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .BindTo(Model.AllStaffStatu)
          .Placeholder("Durumu Seçiniz...")
          .ValuePrimitive(true)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 325px;", @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>

</div>
```

**And Here is My Controller And CreatePersons Method:**

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Domain.Abstract;
using Domain.DataModel.ViewModels;
using Domain.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.DataModel;
namespace Spts2.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{

    public class SptsDataController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
        private readonly SptsUserStore _store;
        private readonly SptsUserManager _manager;
        SptsCtx context = new SptsCtx();

        public SptsDataController(IDataRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _store = new SptsUserStore();
            _manager = new SptsUserManager(_store);
        }

        // GET: Admin/SptsData
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult CreatePerson([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, SptsDataViewModel person)
        {
            var per = _repository.GetAllPersons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.TcKimlik == person.TcKimlik);

            if (person != null && ModelState.IsValid && per == null)
            {
                _repository.Create(person);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException("Hata Oluştu.Kişi sistemde kayıtlı.");
            }

            return Json(_repository.ReadPersons().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public ActionResult ReadPersons([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(_repository.ReadPersons().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExcelExportBranch(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
        {
            var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help!

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: My hunch would be on areas. Look at the data source configuration; you're not specifying the area there. I can't find (right) the Kendo UI documentation for setting the URLs, but check if there's an overload allowing you to specify the area. Also, please check the exact error in your browser dev tools. You'll see the exact URL being called by the grid.

Comment: There is no need to configure area.So the controller is running already in area.There is no problem with Get Requests.Problem is about Post Requests.Exact problem is 404 error.I looked in browser also.